# INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: nn1.hcluster.com/192.168.155.131:9000. Already tri ed 0 time(s)

Tags: hadoop, configuration, administration

I configured an Apache hadoop cluster with 1 Namenode and 2 Datanodes in VMware Workstation and Namenode is working fine, also did ssh-passwordless login too, but when I try to start datanode get the following error?

Under data nodes log getting Retrying error for namenode under both datanodes, whereas I tried to ping and connect with Namenode no error.

```
Below is the log for datanode,

2015-11-14 19:54:22,622 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: STARTUP_MSG:
/************************************************************
STARTUP_MSG: Starting DataNode
STARTUP_MSG:   host = dn2.hcluster.com/192.168.155.133
STARTUP_MSG:   args = []
STARTUP_MSG:   version = 1.2.1
STARTUP_MSG:   build = https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/common/branches/branch-1.2 -r 1503152; compiled by 'mattf' on Mon Jul 22 1
5:23:09 PDT 2013
STARTUP_MSG:   java = 1.8.0_65
************************************************************/
2015-11-14 19:54:23,447 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsConfig: loaded properties from hadoop-metrics2.properties
2015-11-14 19:54:23,485 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source MetricsSystem,sub=Stats registered.
2015-11-14 19:54:23,486 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Scheduled snapshot period at 10 second(s).
2015-11-14 19:54:23,486 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: DataNode metrics system started
2015-11-14 19:54:23,876 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source ugi registered.
2015-11-14 19:54:25,720 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: nn1.hcluster.com/192.168.155.131:9000. Already tri
ed 0 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 SECONDS)
2015-11-14 19:54:27,723 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: nn1.hcluster.com/192.168.155.131:9000. Already tri
ed 1 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 SECONDS)
2015-11-14 19:54:28,726 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: nn1.hcluster.com/192.168.155.131:9000. Already tri
ed 2 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 SECONDS)
2015-11-14 19:54:29,729 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: nn1.hcluster.com/192.168.155.131:9000. Already tri
ed 3 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 SECONDS)
2015-11-14 19:54:30,733 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: nn1.hcluster.com/192.168.155.131:9000. Already tri
ed 4 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 SECONDS)
2015-11-14 19:54:31,753 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: nn1.hcluster.com/192.168.155.131:9000. Already tri
ed 5 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 SECONDS)
2015-11-14 19:54:32,755 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: nn1.hcluster.com/192.168.155.131:9000. Already tri
ed 6 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 SECONDS)
2015-11-14 19:54:33,758 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: nn1.hcluster.com/192.168.155.131:9000. Already tri
ed 7 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 SECONDS)
2015-11-14 19:54:34,762 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: nn1.hcluster.com/192.168.155.131:9000. Already tri
ed 8 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 SECONDS)
2015-11-14 19:54:35,764 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: nn1.hcluster.com/192.168.155.131:9000. Already tri
ed 9 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 SECONDS)
2015-11-14 19:54:35,922 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: java.io.IOException: Call to nn1.hcluster.com/192.168.155.
131:9000 failed on local exception: java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.wrapException(Client.java:1150)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1118)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Invoker.invoke(RPC.java:229)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy4.getProtocolVersion(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC.checkVersion(RPC.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC.getProxy(RPC.java:414)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC.getProxy(RPC.java:392)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC.getProxy(RPC.java:374)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC.getProxy(RPC.java:453)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC.waitForProxy(RPC.java:335)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC.waitForProxy(RPC.java:300)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.startDataNode(DataNode.java:385)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.<init>(DataNode.java:321)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.makeInstance(DataNode.java:1712)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.instantiateDataNode(DataNode.java:1651)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.createDataNode(DataNode.java:1669)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.secureMain(DataNode.java:1795)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.main(DataNode.java:1812)
Caused by: java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
        at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketIOWithTimeout.connect(SocketIOWithTimeout.java:206)
        at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:511)
        at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:481)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupConnection(Client.java:457)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupIOstreams(Client.java:583)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.access$2200(Client.java:205)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getConnection(Client.java:1249)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1093)
        ... 16 more

2015-11-14 19:54:35,952 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: SHUTDOWN_MSG:
/************************************************************
SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down DataNode at dn2.hcluster.com/192.168.155.133
************************************************************/
```

From Datanode 1 and 2, Namenode and it's GUI is working and all 3Desktop are able to communicate with eachother via pin or ssh passwordless too. Please help..

core-site.xml under namenode

```
<configuration>
<property>
<name>fs.default.name</name>
<value>hdfs://nn01.hcluster.com:9000</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure your Namenode is running fine. Otherwise check the Machine IP and host name in **/etc/hosts** file.

Make sure that you have added this hostname **"nn01.hcluster.com"**  there.